# How to integrate CANOE with Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins

I want to integrate CANOE with Jenkins. Can anybody please tell me how to do that. For now I am able to open CANOE window through Jenkins. But it shows a disclaimer on startup. I want to click on "I accept" button automatically through Jenkins using any command. Can you please tell me how to do that or what is that command?. Is there any other way to click on that button without pressing the key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CANoe is implemented as a COM-server. Using the COM-interface, you can start CANoe from a script and thus bypass the disclaimer. I have managed to do this either using C# or python with pywin32. The CANoe help-section contains some help on what COM-server commands are available to get you started.

edit:
If CANoe is associated with cfg-files as standard application, you can call the cfg-file directly and have it launch CANoe. That will still require you to manually click the disclaimer dialog though. In a script, such as the one I mentioned earlier, you can create it in such a way that you are able to specify which cfg-file to use as an input parameter. It can also be written so that you can specify certain test-suites containing your CAPL-scripts. It can basically give you access to most CANoe features necessary to run test-suites with different settings. However, I've not tried a lot of them yet.

Unfortunately, none of your examples can be achieved without creating this kind of script.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But is there any windows batch command to open canoe and load the config file in canoe through command line. I also want to run CAPL script through command line. Could you please help me with that?.

Comment: I am very glad that you answered my question. I want to access the functions of canoe through command line e.g. start,compile etc.Could you please tell me the way to do that? If there is any way that i can do this through bash script then that would be helpful too.

Comment: Sorry, this is as far as you will get just jusing bash-scripts. To access further functionality you must turn to creating a simple COM-client. That COM-client can then be called from bash-script using any number of input parameters depending on how advanced you make the client and how advanced tasks you want to perform. 
I would suggest writing the client in python using the win32com-module from pywin32 because of the acceptable learning threshold. If you are more familiar with other programming languages I guess there are similar modules available to import for them.

Comment: I didn't want to use COM-server but now i think i have to use it.Can you please tell me the python code to open Canoe, load cfg file and run this cfg file. Thanks for your answers.

Comment: As I wrote, the help section in CANoe is the best help I can give you as I don't have the specifics at this point.

Comment: Okay, Thanks for your valuable answers.

Answer (score 0):

CANOE simply loads a .cfg configuration file. For jenkins, I am using the Visual Basics script and same triggering into the Jenkins job.

In this was it bypasses the "I accept" and other windows and loads the desired configuration also also using same kind of VB scirpt you can close the application.

```
'ToStart CANoe_Start.vbs

Set App = CreateObject("CANoe.Application")   
dim fso: set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")   
dim CANoe_config    
CANoe_config = fso.BuildPath(fso.GetAbsolutePathName("."), "<target.cfg>")

App.Measurement.Start()
```

After that you can add the operations in jenkins jobs; to close the same appilcation use :

```
'ToStop CANoe_Stop.vbs
Set App = CreateObject("CANoe.Application")
App.Quit()
```

This worked for me. You can call the vbs's over jenkins jobs.